# How to consume external web services on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, sharepoint-server, wcf

I'm trying to get data out from DB2 mainframe into SharePoint 2010. My Orz use common web services and one of the developers have given me the `WSDL` file that they have used before.

I'm not sure how this has to be consumed? Do I need to get this `WSDL` file to `_vti_bin` under IIS folder? If so, how do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the **WSDL** file is for the external service you want to query, so you don't need to mess around with **_vti_bin** or similar.

Try calling the service from a Console application (without thinking about SharePoint) by adding a [Service Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Then when you have that working you could use the same approach to reference the service, just inside a [Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231519.aspx) in a SharePoint project.
Then use the Web Part to print the data.

**EDIT:**

Try calling out to the service using [Business Connectivity Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as well. A simple way to test this is to fire it up in SharePoint designer and create an external content type.
To use this method you must be able to download the wsdl file from an URL (BSC will use this), you might find an URL inside the WSDL file which points to itself (on the external server).
Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798325.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

One method I have used for SOAP Web Services was to take the asmx file and deploy it to the file system in SharePoint _layouts/TimeZoneWS/TimeZoneWS.asmx.  I deploy it to the farm as a GAC to register it with my SharePoint 14 hive.  Then, I am able to call to it by opening a ServiceProxy in JQuery.

```
var serviceUrl = "http://stormdev-02/_layouts/TimeZoneWS/TimeZoneWS.asmx";

var utcTimeOffsets = [];

function GetUtcOffsets(timezones, func) {


var proxy = new ServiceProxy(serviceUrl);
proxy.isWcf = false;
proxy.invoke("GetUTCOffsets",
    { tzName: timezones },
    function(result) {

        utcTimeOffsets = result;


        if (func) func();

        //return result;

    },
    function(error, i, request) {
        alert("Please select your time zones and your clock preferences.");

    },
    false);
```

}